# Differences in code and sources of errors after re-registering app on different Facebook account

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I was creating a facebook application and a security prompt came up which asked me to verify my mobile number and email.  Unfortunately the mobile number was an old one and the email was my old university one (bad foresight..) which has expired.

Facebook are suspicious of new accounts developing facebook applications because they believe people are making the accounts for the sole purpose, so my only opportunity is to use my friends account to re-register my app.

**I have registered the app and taken the new app id and secret and put them into my application config.php file.**  However the below error is appearing:

**"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MY FOLDER NAME\fb\base_facebook.php on line 1028"**

I have replaced every instance of where my app id and secret were used to I don't understand what could be difference between the two...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token error will be shown when you are trying to access certain information which is not readily accessible without getting access to that user's access token. Thus this does not look like a appid config issue. Try the graph api explorer tool to see if the request goes through

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Also you seem to be using Facebooks test code , you can also test it with some basic Facebook javascript sdk code from here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Also there is getting started code here for php
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth

Try and see if these work for you that will confirm whether the appid is issue or not.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out that some of my code's execution wasn't even conditional on a user being logged in!  God knows how it was working before.